# Replacing Nth Occurrence from End of Line via Sed

Tags: bash, sed

Do you know of a better or easier way of using sed or Bash to replace from the last occurrence of a regex match from the end of a line without using `rev`?

Here is the `rev` way to match the third from last occurrence of the letter 's' – still forward matching, yet utilizing `rev` to match from the last character.

```
echo "a declaration of sovereignty need no witness" | rev | sed 's/s/S/3' | rev
a declaration of Sovereignty need no witness
```

**Update** -- a generalized solution based on Cyruses answer:

```
SEARCH="one" 
OCCURRENCE=3 
REPLACE="FOUR" 
SED_DELIM=$'\001'  
SEARCHNEG=$(sed 's/./[^&]*/g' <<< "${SEARCH}")
sed -r "s${SED_DELIM}${SEARCH}((${SEARCHNEG}${SEARCH}){$((${OCCURRENCE}-1))}${SEARCHNEG})\$${SED_DELIM}${REPLACE}\1${SED_DELIM}"  <<< "one one two two one one three three one one"
```

Note: To be truly generic it should escape regex items from the LHS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/s(([^s]*s){2}[^s]*)$/S\1/'  file
```

Output:

```
a declaration of Sovereignty need no witness
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: Thanks, this works for the single letter I used as an example but for a word regex `[^s]`-->`[^importantword]` won't match as expected. Matching back off the end-anchor is a concept that works.

Comment: To match an `importantword` first reduce the said word to a unique single character, then match as above and then reinstate the unchanged words.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
str='a declaration of sovereignty need no witness'

awk -v r='S' -v n=3 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="s"} {
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF)?(i==NF-n?r:OFS):ORS}' <<< "$str"
```

**Output:**

```
a declaration of Sovereignty need no witness
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to count the number of occurances and figure out which one to replace:

```
echo "importantword1 importantword2 importantword3 importantword4 importantword5 importantword6" | 
    grep -o "importantword" | wc -l
```

Use that for your sed string

```
echo "importantword1 importantword2 importantword3 importantword4 importantword5 importantword6" |
   sed 's/\(\(.*importantword.*\)\{3\}\)importantword\(\(.*importantword.*\)\{2\}\)/\1ExportAntword\3/'
importantword1 importantword2 importantword3 ExportAntword4 importantword5 importantword6
```

You get the same answer with setting variables for left and right:

```
l=3
r=2
echo "importantword1 importantword2 importantword3 importantword4 importantword5 importantword6" |
  sed 's/\(\(.*importantword.*\)\{'$l'\}\)importantword\(\(.*importantword.*\)\{'$r'\}\)/\1ExportAntword\3/'
```

or

```
str="\(.*importantword.*\)"
echo "importantword1 importantword2 importantword3 importantword4 importantword5 importantword6" | 
   sed 's/\('${str}'\{'$l'\}\)importantword\('${str}'\{'$r'\}\)/\1ExportAntword\3/'
```

Answer (score 0):

In Perl, you can use a look-ahead assertion:

```
echo "a declaration of sovereignty need no witness" \
| perl -pe 's/s(?=(?:[^s]*s[^s]*){2}$)/S/'
```

- `(?=...)` is the look-ahead assertion, it means "if followed by ...", but the ... part is not matched and therefore not substituted
- `[^s]*s[^s]*` means there's only one `s` wrapped possibly by non-`s`es
- `{2}` is the number of repetitions, i.e. we want *two* s'es after the one we want to replace